# How to return and set to zero?

Tags: java

I want to ask one question. If the amount is greater than the balance than I have to return the whole balance and set the balance to zero.. How can I do that? I have tried many different ways to solve this but it didn't work. Thanks for your help.

```
public class BankAccount {
    double balance;

    BankAccount(double openingBalance){
        balance=openingBalance;
    }
        public double getBalance(){
        return balance; 
    }
    public void deposit(double amount){
        balance += amount;
    }
    public double withdraw (double amount){ 
        if (balance > amount){
            balance -= amount;
        }else if (amount > balance || amount == balance){       
            **return balance; 
            balance = 0**
        }   
        return amount;
    }
}
```

Driver class

```
public class Driver {

    static BankAccount acc3;

    public static void main (String[] args){
        BankAccount  acc3 = new BankAccount ("Alana","Neil", 5000);
        System.out.println("\nName: " +acc3.Name());
        System.out.println("Amount: $" +acc3.balance);
        acc3.deposit(100);
        System.out.println("Deposit Amount: $" +acc3.balance);
        System.out.println("Withdrawl Amount: $"+acc3.withdraw(5400));
        System.out.println("The New Balance: $" +acc3.balance);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use  a temporary variable:

```
double tmp = balance;
balance = 0;
return tmp;
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be simpler if you just did coded what you meant (change the amount when the balance isn't enough):

```
public double withdraw (double amount){
    if (amount > balance) {
        amount = balance;
    }
    balance -= amount;
    return amount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The else part can be:

```
}
else {
    amount = this.balance;
    this.balance = 0;
}
```

So you fulfil the requirement to return only the balance that could be withdrawn, and also to set the remaining balance to zero.

Answer (score 0):

First you dont need to return amount, since you pass it to the method. 
And that you whant to return? the error that amount is to big or just amount of capable of withdrawing? 
And For the method:

```
public double withdraw (double amount){ 
    if (balance > amount){
        balance -= amount;
    }else{ //no need for second if since we check in first 
             // if amount is smaller then balance
        // if you whant to withdraw all money
        return balance = 0; // 
        // or return -1 and in balance method change if balance = -1 you are broke
        return balance = -1;
    }   
    return balance;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public double withdraw (double amount){

     double toReturn = amount;

    if (balance > amount){
        balance -= amount;
    }
    else if (amount > balance) {
        toReturn = balance;      
        balance = 0;
    }
    else if (amount == balance){ 
        balance = 0;
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```